# How to install default ubuntu (17.10) packages and softwares

Tags: ubuntu-17.10

I dual booted with Ubuntu 17.10 . However it does not contain the pre-installed default softwares like `gcc` and `make`.
I have tried `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` to try and install such packages but no success.
I have looked online for this problem but have found no solutions. How should I install all the default softwares at once (not manually install them one by one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential
```

See also: [Installing Compilers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers)